# Import data from 64-bit ODBC provider

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssms, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to migrate PostGIS database to SQL-Server 2008 spatial database.
PostgreSQL installs 64 bit ODBC driver.

If I try to import data from PostgreSQL ODBC provider with SSMS I get this error:

`ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application`

which I assume means that I can't to connect with 64-bit driver, as SSMS is 32-bit.

Any advice how to solve this?

Comment: Solution was straight-forward: I installed additional 32-bit PostgreSQL ODBC driver and successfully connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ODBC driver architecture must match the architecture of the application, as an ODBC driver is a library that's loaded in-process.

So if your app is 32-bit, the ODBC driver must be 32-bit as well, irrespective of whether it's a 32-bit or 64-bit PostgreSQL server.